# How to count a phrase in Big Query view

Tags: google-bigquery

I have `fir-ui-af***:firestore_export` dataset in my BigQuery project.

In this dataset, I have `speech_raw_changelog` table and `speech_raw_latest` view.

This is schema of `speech_raw_latest` view.
[image]

In `data` field which I marked with a red pen, there is JSON data.
This is an example of field and value in `data`.
[image]

I would like to count the number of ******ka@gmail.com in `email` field in this `speech_raw_latest` view.

I searched the Internet and found that I should use COUNT function, but I don't know how to use it to solve my problem.

Could you give me any advice, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT COUNTIF(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.email') = 'ka@gmail')
FROM `project.dataset.speech_raw_latest`
```